# Jssor slider on mobile phone

Tags: mobile, slider, width, percentage, jssor

I want to make jssor slider on mobile phone (max-width: 360px) height 70%. I scale it to 70% but it dont fit on screen, any ideas? Here is script:

```
function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                refSize = Math.min(refSize, 1920);
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize * 1);

            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            if(refSize <= 360){
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleHeight(jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientHeight*0.7);
            }
        }

        ScaleSlider();
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", ScaleSlider);
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end

    };
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? right now, you are scaling twice, 1st to clientWidth (360) and then to 70% of clientHeight (defined in the div which is wrapping the image)

Comment: @Vickel 
I want that my slider, then my screen width 360px or less , would be fixed 70% height and responsive width, from this code my slider have 70% height, but width is 1920px, here is picture of it: 
[link](http://oi67.tinypic.com/vh4yns.jpg)

Comment: don't use http://tinypic.com ! It seems to be full of crap! stackoverflow uses https://imgur.com/. Anyway, please place your relevant html code. Are your images landscape, portrait or mixed?

Comment: @Vickel Thanks for tip, landscape, here is a bit body code:

 `<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden;">`

       `<div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1300px; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div data-p="225.00" style="display: none;">
                <img data-u="image" src="img/red.jpg" />`

Comment: when im changing width to percent js automaticly converts it to pixels...